# How to list down all useless or less used files or application in my linux server?

Tags: command-line, command-history, oracle-linux, disk-cleanup

I want to clean cruft from my Oracle Linux server. For this, I need to know which application or directory isn't used or is hardly ever accessed. Is there any command or way to list directories or applications that meet those criteria.

Comment: Do you need the disk space, or are you just doing this because you think it needs to be done?

Comment: I need disk space.

Comment: Ok, then the first step is to figure out what kind of stuff is using space. Is it installed programs? user data? backups? etc. It's rare that installed programs are the problems, but it can happen if it's a special-purpose server with little user data. Start by posting the output of `df`.

Comment: @Gilles: What is the best way to follow your suggestion? Is there any command which will list down with their size and last used date?

Comment: By default, last used date isn't tracked. Before you try to investigate that further, check whether it's installed programs that are using the disk space.

Answer (score 2):

```
find / -type f -atime +90
```

will list all files that haven't been read in at least 90 days, if your system tracks file access times.

Beware that modern Linux systems don't track file access times by default, so the output of this command of a typical system is not useful. To enable file access time tracking, run the command

```
mount -o remount,atime /
```

Then wait for a month or so, and run the `find` command again to see which files' access time has been updated.

Note that it's hard to achieve this for directories. Simply listing the contents of a directory will update its access time -- the above `find` command has to read every directory, so all their access times will be updated.

Comment: You could mount the filesystems using the `noatime` option before performing the scan with `find`. I guess it's a bit fiddly doing that for `/`, though.

Comment: And it doesn't help if someone has previously done similar `find` commands. Also, some backup scripts might do similar things. The point is that it's really easy to inadvertently update the `atime` of directories.

Comment: True enough. Even listing them in a GUI file manager can update the atime.

Comment: This answer would have been useful a decade ago. But nowadays Linux defaults to relatime, which means that the atime of an executable is likely to remain equal to the ctime, which is the time the executable was installed.